# Adding error bars to an existing plot using values from a column

Tags: r, plot, addition, confidence-interval

I am having problems trying to add the 95% CI (lower/upper) to an existing plot using the values from two columns in a matrix. What would be the best way to use this information to add the error bars?

Here is a sample of my data:

> ```
> option<-read.table(text="
> distance p.move id option   mean lower95%CI upper95%CI
> 1      close   0.05  1    10% 13.682     11.306     15.768
> 2      close   0.10  2    10% 10.886      9.336     12.270
> 3      close   0.15  3    10%  8.402      7.262      9.580
> 4      close   0.20  4    10%  7.240      6.132      8.350
> 5      close   0.25  5    10%  6.322      5.288      7.370
> 6      close   0.30  6    10%  5.850      4.920      6.714
> 7      close   0.35  7    10%  3.838      3.084      4.648
> 8      close   0.40  8    10%  3.600      2.936      4.200
> 9      close   0.45  9    10%  3.380      2.702      4.016
> 10     close   0.50 10    10%  3.152      2.462      3.720
> 11     close   0.55 11    10%  2.772      2.214      3.286
> 12     close   0.60 12    10%  3.072      2.458      3.596
> 13     close   0.65 13    10%  2.670      2.134      3.212
> 14     close   0.70 14    10%  2.194      1.724      2.634
> 15     close   0.75 15    10%  1.980      1.612      2.336
> 16     close   0.80 16    10%  2.028      1.594      2.466
> 17     close   0.85 17    10%  1.650      1.294      1.974
> 18     close   0.90 18    10%  1.916      1.564      2.254",header=T)
>
> option
> ```

This is my plot:

> ```
> plot(option$mean~option$p.move,xlim=c(0,1),type="o",ylim=c(0,20),
> xlab="Probability",ylab="% time",col=1,lwd=1.85)
> ```

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: If you just want to additionally plot those extra columns in the same way as you plotted `option$mean`, see `?lines` which draws lines in the same way as `plot` but draws on the existing plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the extra columns in with `lines` which is like `plot` but draws on the existing plot. (see `?lines`, `?points`).

Also, when you `plot` with a data frame you can skip all the `option$` by feeding `option` into the `dat` argument (see `?plot`):

```
# draw original plot
plot(mean ~ p.move, dat=option, xlim=c(0,1), type="o", ylim=c(0,20),
     xlab="Probability",ylab="% time",col=1,lwd=1.85)

# draw extra lines (the '%' in the column names gets converted to '.' by R)
# note you can put your usual `plot` arguments into `lines` like lwd, type etc
# if you want
lines(upper95.CI ~ p.move, option)
lines(lower95.CI ~ p.move, option)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for actual error bars, but this looks good too,

Comment: Oh, OK. you mean the vertical lines extending from each point? Confidence intervals are typically plotted as lines whereas error bars are typically plotted as the vertical lines. You can use `lines` and draw in the vertical lines yourself. Each `x` coordinate is `p.move` and the `y` coordinates go from `lower95.CI` to `upper95.CI`.

Comment: `plotCI` from the `plotrix` package (there is a version in the `gplots` package) is one possibility: see http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-base:errbars